# How to extract parts of a GWT application into a library of separate dialogs

Tags: gwt, module, entry-point

I'm trying to extract parts of a GWT application into many separate dialogs that can be invoked from php.

**Existing state**: 
We have a GWT appplication that is deployed to JBoss as a WAR.
The app has a single module with a signle entry point.
The main JSP sets up the environment and then has some JS that loads the .nocache.js using document.write();
The entry point's onModuleLoad() creates a panel to fill the browser and adds it to the root using RootPanel.get("root").add();
When some event happens (e.g., user presses button) we pop up a DialogBox by instatiating a subclass and calling center() or setVisible()

**Desired state**:
We want a php app with multiple pages, to be able to invoke various DialogBox subclasses.

I think that the php side should use JS function calls that use document.write();
As for the GWT side, the options I see are:

1. One module with multiple entry points.
2. Multiple modules.

Does anyone have any experience or understanding of what would be the best practice here?

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood right, you need to call GWT methods from Javascript.
You can use JSNI.
But I think you should try gwt-exporter on the GWT side. [Overview](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/wiki/GettingStarted). [Tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/gwtchismes/wiki/Tutorial_ExportingGwtLibrariesToJavascript_en).
It's simple GWT module to create JS_API for your GWT modules.

Not pretending to be the best practices, just quick example.

On the server-side you include an existing GWT module with DialogBoxes on every page.
You need to modify this GWT module or create new like this.

```
public class GwtModule implements EntryPoint {
@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {

    // exportable class
    DialogBoxManager dbm = new DialogBoxManager();

    // export all Exportable classes of module
    ExporterUtil.exportAll();

    // needed cause JS_API will be available only after the GWT is loaded
    onLoad();
}

// call when GWT module loaded
private native void onLoad() /*-{
    $wnd.loaded();
}-*/;
```

DialogBoxManager looks like this

```
@Export
@ExportPackage("pkg")
public class DialogBoxManager implements ClickHandler, Exportable {

    private DialogBox db;

    public DialogBoxManager() {

        this.db = new DialogBox();
    }

    @Export("showDB")
    public void showDialog() {

        db.setVisible(true);
        db.center();
        db.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

        showDialog();
    }

}
```

String values in @Export("show"), @ExportPackage("pkg"), etc. annotations will be used in our JS_API calls for annotated GWT methods (you can export also fields).
You can use just @Export (as I did for DialogBoxManager).

When GWT module is loaded in your JS library you can realize initialization of JS_API member or what you need

```
var dbManager = null;
...


 function loaded() {
        dbManager = new pkg.DialogBoxManager();
    }
```

and then just call JS_API like this

```
function showDB() {
        if (dbManager != null) {
            dbManager.showDB();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I found a simpler solution here: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#calling So i can write in onModuleLoad(): $wnd.computeLoanInterest =           $entry(@mypackage.MyUtilityClass::computeLoanInterest(IFI));

Comment: JSNI is the choice if the new project all will be written with GWT. Also it's preferred one module aggregating other modules per host page. But you can use as more as if you want.